# Why does the equation $\frac{1}{2}mv_i^2+K\frac{Qq}{r_i}=\frac{1}{2}mv_f^2+K\frac{Qq}{r_f}$ not apply here?

Tags: electrostatics, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy, inertial-frames

Two particles at rest with positive charges $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ respectively are separated $3cm$ apart. After some time, they become $12cm$ apart. Compute the final velocity of each particle at that point.

According to a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEQxtUwiV1E&ab_channel=KhanAcademyPhysics) by Khan Academy, the correct fromula to use is $$K\frac{Q_1Q_2}{r_i}=K\frac{Q_1Q_2}{r_f}+\text{KE}_{f}$$

where

$$\text{KE}_f=\frac{1}{2}m_1v_{1f}^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2v_{2f}^2$$

---

I would have thought, however, that the correct formula to use for one particle particle with mass $m_k$ was

$$K\frac{Q_1Q_2}{r_i}=K\frac{Q_1Q_2}{r_f}+\frac{1}{2}m_kv_{kf}^2$$

since $$\frac{1}{2}mv_{k}^2(t_f)-\frac{1}{2}mv_{k}^2(t_i)=\int^{r_k(t_f)}_{r_k(t_i)}\vec{F}_k(\vec{r}_k(t))\cdot \vec{v}_k(t)dt=-K\frac{Q_kQ_j}{r_k(t_f)}+K\frac{Q_kQ_j}{r_k(t_i)}$$

where $\vec{r}$ is the particle's position with respect to time, and $Q_j$ is the other particle.

Comment: You should link to the relevant video / web page.

Comment: @cms Thanks, I added a link to the video.

Comment: Note that it says the particles start at rest. That implies $KE_i = 0$

Answer (score 0):

So let's get the first thing out of the way, you keep putting an $r^2$ in the denominator, that video takes great pains to say that it needs to be $r$ in the denominator, not squared. Get this right or you will be very confused when you do dimensional analysis and/or calculations. :)

Second thing, the thing you will learn about energy balances is that they are a crude tool and need to be understood that way. Conservation of energy is a sort of sledgehammer, it cannot be invoked to do nice little details.

So, if you have a system of 3 interacting particles, conservation of energy **always always always** works by adding their energies all together. Your question is essentially, “With conservation of energy I have 1 equation for 1 particle, 2 equations for 2 particles, 3 equations for 3 particles—right?” and the answer is an emphatic **no**. You have 1 equation for 1 particle, 1 equation for 2 particles, 1 equation for 3 particles... they don’t each get a separate conservation of energy!

Now, you *can* sometimes create separate equations, let me tell you how. First, you're going to want to draw an abstract diagram called an undirected graph. In this undirected graph, we draw a circle for each particle that can move, and then you are going to want to draw a line between dots if the moving particles have a force between each other. For example,

[image: a graph with 7 points marked 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, points 1,2,3 form a triangle on the left, while 4,5,6,7 form a quadrilateral on the right.]

In this case, you see that the graph is *disconnected*, there is a triangle on the left and a quadrilateral on the right but there are no links between the two. Since no forces can carry energy from the particles on the left to the particles on the right, then you can say that the particles on the left have a constant energy and the particles on the right have a separate constant energy. In place of “force” you might need to substitute other notions for example “thermal contact” that can transfer energy, too.

But, energy does not give you more information to let you “peek inside” the one or the other, it just says that all the energy in those systems must be constant, it doesn't prevent energy from flowing from circle 1 to circles 2 and 3 or vice versa, or from flowing from circles 2 and 3 into the line $L_{23}$ between them (the potential energy of their interaction). It cannot say where exactly the energy is, just that it was neither created nor destroyed and so it must still be in there somewhere.

This flaw in the “energy picture”, that it does not seem to specify the equations of motion or the detailed energy flows, is rectified with a bit of mathematical trickery called **variational calculus** later, so it turns out that from the Hamiltonian or Lagrangian functions, both of which are energy-based, you get the equations of motion back and you can find the actual energy flows from the *functional forms* of these functions. But the conservation principle is just the most basic statement about the Hamiltonian/Lagrangian, that it does not explicitly depend on time.

As an aside this is why most of the applied physicists I have met, on the rare occasions when I talk to them about the “a calorie is a calorie” thinking that dieticians have, seem to find its logic surprising. The reason we get surprised is because we have done lots of practice exercises and the “energy picture” needs these complex mathematical tricks to recover any sort of detail. Complex systems cannot be uniquely determined by their most basic constraints.

Comment: You are right about the $r^2$. I fixed it.

Comment: I'm still puzzled as to why the last equation I wrote does not apply here. It still seems to me that it should hold.

Comment: Is the other particle fixed in place? Because if so then it holds.